# To make a login cookie by POST data by PHP

Tags: php, post

**How can you make a login cookie of the POST -data by PHP?**

*My code registration.php*

```
global $login_cookie = $_POST['email'] . ',' . md5($_POST['password']);  
    // this does not work: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'

setcookie("login_cookie", $login_cookie);            
      // this is empty because of the above
```

where the two pieces of POST data are not empty.

I run the following test-commands at index.php

```
 echo $login_cookie;       
 print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I get `nothing`.

The problem is in the first declaration of $login_cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a syntax error because that line of code is invalid.

```
global $login_cookie = $_POST['email'] . ',' . md5($_POST['password']);
```

should be:

```
global $login_cookie;
$login_cookie = $_POST['email'] . ',' . md5($_POST['password']);
```

You should read up on the [global keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and be sure you're using it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
global $login_cookie;
$login_cookie = $_POST['email'] . ',' . md5($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't assign a value for the variable when declaring it global. Do it separately:

```
global $login_cookie;  
$login_cookie = $_POST['email'] . ',' . md5($_POST['password']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `global`, it probably does not mean what you think it means.